# How to Convert text file to CSV in python

Tags: python, sed

I need to convert text file to csv file.Below command is not working in python, which is working fine in shell prompt.Please help me to fix the issue.

```
subprocess.call("sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' test.txt > test.csv")
```

Content of test.txt

```
jega mca
divya BE
ramya MA
```

Comment: you should use the csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `shell=True`

```
subprocess.call("sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' test.txt > test.csv", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` library to do that. The following code might work:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.to_csv(test.csv, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe use plain python:

```
result = ''

with open('file.txt') as f:
    result = '\n'.join(f.readlines())

with open('output.csv') as f:
    for line in result.split('\n'):
        line = line.replace(' ', ',')
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) python library:

```
import csv
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    with open('test.csv', 'w+',  newline = '') as csvFile:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = ' ')
        for elem in content:
            csvWriter.writerow([elem.strip()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python **[csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)** module gives better control than **[pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)** in my opinion:

```
import csv

with open('txt_file.txt', 'r') as txt_file:
    # Strip out whitespace from line
    stripped_lines = [line.strip() for line in txt_file] 
    # Break up each line based on delimiter
    enlisted_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in stripped_lines if line]

    # Write lines to a CSV file using the csv package
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_output:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_output)
        csv_writer.writerows(enlisted_lines)
```