# Convert Text Files in a Folder to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, text, delimiter

I have a folder **RPT_AR** which has 3 files :2 text files and 1 csv file namely RPT_AR1.csv, RPT_AR2.txt, RPT_AR3.txt and I want to convert the text files to CSV

I tried to following code in Python

```
import os  
import fnmatch  
import pandas as pd  
files_dir = r'C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Desktop\Scrub_Data\RPT_AR'  
files = os.listdir(files_dir)
```

```
for file in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'RPT_AR*'):
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        filename = os.path.join(files_dir, file)
        if extension =='.txt':
            pd.read_csv(r'filename',sep='|')
            filename.to_csv(r'filename')
```

but it is giving error EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481721/how-to-convert-text-file-to-csv-in-python
The above link answers the same but for a single text file and not for multiple text files in a folder

Comment: You found a link that shows you how to do it for one file. Read the answer that uses pandas _carefully_. What does it do that you do incorrectly in your code?

Comment: I did try using that what it was throwing EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Answer (score 1):

```
import os  
import fnmatch  
import pandas as pd  

files_dir = r'C:\Users\rajat.kapoor\Desktop\Scrub_Data\RPT_AR'  
files = os.listdir(files_dir) 

for file in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'RPT_AR*'):
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        if extension =='.txt':
            filename = os.path.join(files_dir, file)
            df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='|')
            new_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.csv'
            df.to_csv(new_filename, index=False)
```

With these changes, the code should read each text file in the directory, parse it using pd.read_csv(), and then save the resulting DataFrame to a new CSV file with the same name as the original text file.

Comment: Ok. I Tried but This is throwing EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file